# How to compare the value while accessing through forEach tag of JSTl

Tags: java, compare, jstl

```
  <c:forEach var="healthp" items="${healthparam}" >
  <tr>
 <td><c:out value="${healthp.name}"/></td>
 <td><c:out value="${healthp.current_Reading}"/></td>
 <td><c:out value="${healthp.target}"/></td>
 <td><c:out value="${healthp.measurementunit}"/></td>
 <td><c:out value="${healthp.target}"/></td>
 <td><c:out value="${healthp.recorddate}"/></td>  
  </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

In This I want to compare the Current_Reading with the target.
if the current reading have higher value then only i want to show in that (Current_Reading)column otherwise i want to show it on target column.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can use the c:if tag. If I understand you correctly and you want to hide the value in either current_Reading or target (whichever is lower), then it could look like this:

```
  <td><c:out value="${healthp.name}"/></td>
  <td>
    <c:if test="${healthp.current_Reading > healthp.target}">
      <c:out value="${healthp.current_Reading}"/>
    </c:if>
  </td>
  <td><c:out value="${healthp.target}"/></td>
  <td><c:out value="${healthp.measurementunit}"/></td>
  <td>
    <c:if test="${healthp.current_Reading <= healthp.target}">
      <c:out value="${healthp.target}"/>
    </c:if>
  </td>
  <td><c:out value="${healthp.recorddate}"/></td>
```

This will leave you with one empty column, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Nice answer. But looks like OP wants to display  Current_Reading in both the conditions. But based on conditions OP wants to display this value in different columns.

Comment: thanks  and let me check whether it is working or not

Answer (score 1):

you can use eq as well as ne, lt, etc  while using expression language.

```
<c:if test="${var1 eq var2}">some code</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this technique is what you are looking for.  The "ternary" operator is a clean way to display the higher of two values in a single column:

```
<c:forEach var="healthp" items="${healthparam}" >
<tr>
    <td><c:out value="${healthp.name}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${healthp.current_Reading > healthp.target ? healthp.current_Reading : healthp.target}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${healthp.measurementunit}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${healthp.target}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${healthp.recorddate}"/></td>  
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Side note:  Most modern JSP implementations don't require c:out anymore, so you can make your code more readable by doing this:

```
<c:forEach var="healthp" items="${healthparam}">
<tr>
    <td>${healthp.name}</td>
    <td>${healthp.current_Reading > healthp.target ? healthp.current_Reading : healthp.target}</td>
    <td>${healthp.measurementunit}</td>
    <td>${healthp.target}</td>
    <td>${healthp.recorddate}</td>  
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: thanks  and let me check whether it is working or not